# google cloud apigateway with dynamic endpoints

Tags: google-cloud-platform, yaml, google-cloud-api-gateway, google-api-gateway

I am using the google apigateway with the following structure:
an endpoint called 'product' and then a product id. Hence each product gives a different url. E.g. my first product might be https://www.my-endpoint/product/1 and the second would be https://www.my-endpoint/product/2

I know how to do this if it was a parameter based endpoint. If the endpoint was called product-info, and had a unique product number, I could do something like the following, and pass in a parameter. E.g. https://www.my-endpoint/product-info?productid=1 to get the info of the first product, but I can't figure out what to do when it's a different url for what would be each query parameter

```
 "/product-info":
    get:
      x-google-backend:
        address: https://my-endpoint/product-info
      operationId: "product-id-endpoint"
      parameters:
        -
          name: iataCode
          in: query
          required: false
          type: string
      responses:
        200:
          description: "Success."
          schema:
            type: string
        400:
          description: "Failed"
```

Is this not possible? I can make it work on AWS apigateway, thought it should be possible on google cloud as well

Comment: Please provide more details regarding your concern or share any documents that you followed? Also, I would like to clarify what you are expected to do here.

Comment: Objective/concern: on AWS apigateway I can set as the base url of api, say. https://my-address.com

THen, I can pass through to this apigateway, https://my-address.com/product/1

However, on google cloud it seems like I'd need to create a different endpoint for each product. E.g., an endpoint for https://my-address.com/product/1, https://my-address.com/product/2, https://my-address.com/product/3 etc.

Documentations: I followed the standard docs to create the api https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/about-dev-env

Comment: Could you please try to check if these two documentations [Cloud Endpoints in Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/set-up-cloud-run-espv2) and [Microservices in App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/microservices-on-app-engine) address your concerns?